# testng.xml with cross browser

Tags: selenium, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I am having some issue launching browsers in selenium java using testNg with the xml file. The code seems to be working just fine when there is no "driver = new ChromeDriver();" is involved I am attaching everything I have so far

So her is my class file

```
package corssBrowsers;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class VerifyTitle {

WebDriver driver;

@Test(priority=1)
public void sam() {
    System.out.println("Hello sam");
}

@Test(priority = 2)
@Parameters({"browser"})
public void browsers(String browsername) {

    System.out.println(browsername);

    if(browsername.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        System.out.println("You have selected " + browsername);

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Drivers\\Windows\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();

    }
    else {
        System.out.println("You have not selected chrome");
    }

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("www.yahoo.com");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}


}
```

and my testng.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">



<test name="Test">

<parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>

<classes>
<class name="corssBrowsers.VerifyTitle"/>
</classes>

</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

When I run the test form the xml I keep getting :

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
Hello sam
chrome
You have selected chrome
Starting ChromeDriver 2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91) 
on port 13932
Only local connections are allowed.

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

and when I run form the class file I get :

```
PASSED: sam
FAILED: browsers
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'browser' is required by @Test on method browsers but has not been 
marked @Optional or defined
```

In both cases, chrome browser doesn't launch even though the code is correct (works fine in other tests I did). So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using latest chromedriver.exe as well as latest selenium jars? Provide what exception you got

Answer (score 0):

**browsers** method has parameter and this parameter is defined in the TestNG XML.So, If you are running the test in the class level, then system will not get the browser name and will throw an error . You can add the optional tag in the parameter, if the values are not specified in the testng xml or if you are running in the class level, then optional annotation value will be taken as a default value.

You need to modified the code as below

```
public void browsers(@Optional("chrome") String browsername) {

    System.out.println(browsername);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add default value for the browsername parameter, let's think about it together.
You added a parameter in the xml runner file for the browser and when you run the file the parameter passes to the @Test where you declared @Parameters.
Now if you run the test class it self, the value will not pass to @Test from the xml file cuz nothing launched the file which you need to run as TestNG runner.

Please add default value like this as parameter:

```
@Test(priority = 2)
@Parameters({"browser"})
public void browsers(@Optional("chrome") String browsername){

System.out.println(browsername);

if(browsername.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
    System.out.println("You have selected " + browsername);

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Drivers\\Windows\\chromedriver.exe");

    driver = new ChromeDriver();

}
else {
    System.out.println("You have not selected chrome");
}

driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("www.yahoo.com");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

}

One more last note, try to use the TestNG annotations for setup configurations. I suggest to use @BeforClass for the driver creation.